# C++ Loop to find Min, Max, Avg and Sum of user Inputs

Tags: c++

I was asked to write a program to find the minimum, maximum, average and sum of user inputs and I came up with the following program but there seems to be a problem with the loop I'm using because the program just exits when compiled. Can someone please point the errors to me?
Thank you so much.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool empty = true;
    int max, min, count, avg, sum=0;
    char choice;

    for (count = 0; count++;)

    {

        do
        {
            cout << "Enter a number: ";

            int num;
            cin >> num;

            if (empty)
            {
                empty = false;
                min = num;
                max = num;
            }
            else if (max < num)
            {
                max = num;
            }
            else if (num < min)
            {
                min = num;
            }

            sum = sum + num;

            avg = sum / count;

            cout << "Do you want to continue?: ";
            cin >> choice;
        } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

        if (!empty)
        {
            cout << " Maximum is " << max << endl;
            cout << " Minimum  is " << min << endl;
                    cout << " Sum is " << sum << endl;
            cout << " Average is " << avg << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `for` loop is incorrect:

```
for (count = 0; count++;)
```

Remember that a for loop is:

```
for (initialization; expression; update)
```

`count++` adds 1 to `count` but returns its original value `0`, which is converted to `false`. Because the `expression` is false, the loop stops.

Comment: Can I ask you just another question If I may? Is there a way to get at least two inputs before asking do you want to continue?

Comment: @user3552400 `int num2; cin >> num2`? BTW if the problem is solved you should accept the appropriate answer.

Comment: @user3552400 You can keep a bool `stop`, which is set to false at the start. Then in your loop, check if `count >= 2`, if so, ask the user if he wants to continue. If he doesn't, set stop to true (if count is 1, you don't do anything). And then change your while-statement to `while(!stop)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problematic line

```
        avg = sum / count;
```

in the first iteration of the loop when `count` is set to `0`.

I suggest you remove that line from the loop and put it after the loop.

I would also change when `count` is incremented. It needs to be incremented right after you read a number.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in you `for` expression.

A `for` loop is of the form `for(<init>; <condition>; <step>){<body>}`, the init statement gets executed once at the beginning, then the condition gets checked. If the condition evaluates to `true`, the body gets executed, and then the `step` statement. After that we go back to `condition`, and keep going like that until `condition` evaluates to true.

In your loop, you have `count++` as your condition. An expression of the form `value++` first returns value, and then increments value. So in your case, the first time the condition gets executed, it evaluates to `0`. `0` is equivalent to false, so the loop exits immediately.

In your program, you don't really seem to need the for-loop. All the looping is being done in the `do-while`-construct. To fix your code, you should set count to 0 before the do-while loop, and then increment count every time the user has entered a number (so right after `cin`).

A working version would look something like this:

```
int main()
{
    bool empty = true;
    int max, min, count = 0, avg, sum=0;
    char choice;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";

        int num;
        cin >> num;
        count++;

        if (empty)
        {
            empty = false;
            min = num;
            max = num;
        }
        else if (max < num)
        {
            max = num;
        }
        else if (num < min)
        {
            min = num;
        }

        sum = sum + num;

        avg = sum / count;

        cout << "Do you want to continue?: ";
        cin >> choice;
    } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

    if (!empty)
    {
        cout << " Maximum is " << max << endl;
        cout << " Minimum  is " << min << endl;
                cout << " Sum is " << sum << endl;
        cout << " Average is " << avg << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: re "An expression of the form value++ first returns value, and then increments value.", no there is no time ordering for the built-in post increment. The C++11 standard describes the value of that expression in §5.2.5/1: "The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand. [Note: the value obtained is a copy of
the original value —end note "

Comment: What exactly do you mean? `int value=0; int value2 = value++; int value3 = ++value;` would give (0, 0, 2), right? If you're getting at the fact that you can get UB if you stick multiple post-increments together, that doesn't really seem relevant here. It's called a _post_-increment for a reason, that certainly implies time-ordering, right?

Comment: @user3552400 Great! But you should still get rid of your for-loop (it doesn't do anything anymore at this point), otherwise you won't be able to quit your program.

Comment: it's called post-increment for historical reasons (the machine code instructions of a PDP-something at Bell Labs in 1974 or thereabouts). today the only remnant is that name, and that the operator is a *postfix* operator. and no, no time ordering is implied. just to put that in perspective, also indexing like x[i] is a postfix operator. but consider that you can also write that as i[x].

Comment: _The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand._ So the expression evaluates to the original, unincremented value? How this gets implemented at the lowest-level isn't really relevant. In this case, the time ordering is a useful abstraction. Or maybe I'm just misinterpreting your point..?

Comment: as you remarked yourself, the time ordering abstraction misleads many people into thinking expressions are well-defined when they have Undefined Behavior. it's a schildt-like explanation. dangerous anti-meme.

Comment: Hmm... I get your point, but I think learning the language (and programming in general) is easier if you first learn things that are 'almost correct', and then work out the finer details later. It's like telling kids in high school maths that they can't take the square root of a negative number. Besides, you have to do some pretty crazy stuff before this gets problematic. Something like `i = i++`.

Comment: @JSQuareD Yes, I did as you mentioned and it now works fine. Now trying to implement the two input thing, thanks again.

Comment: @JSquareD: it may depend on which country. in high school (admittedly that was around 1980) we did differential equations, pretty difficult if you don't have complex numbers... ;-) let's adopt explanatory models that work internationally, yes?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf We got around to complex numbers as well, but just not right away. It's a white lie. Maybe this didn't apply to complex numbers in your case, but I find it hard to believe that in no stage of your education you were first taught an approximation, or half truth. How were atoms and molecules first described to you? The concept of electricity? When you first learned about light, were  you immediately told about the underlying quantum mechanics? Sure, physics and computer science are two different worlds. But the concept of abstraction underpins both of them.

Comment: @JSquareD: in this case a **correct explanation** is just as simple as the misleading (time-order) one. if not simpler. there is no good reason to mislead learners.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well.. Maybe you're right. Let's just agree to disagree ;)

Answer (score -1):

How about this which gets rid of the outer loop entirely.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int count = 0, avg = 0, sum = 0;
    char choice;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";

        int num;
        cin >> num;
        ++count;
        max = std::max(max, num);
        min = std::min(min, num);
        sum += num;
        avg = sum / count;

        cout << "Do you want to continue?: ";
        cin >> choice;
    } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

    if (count > 1)
    {
        cout << " Maximum is " << max << endl;
        cout << " Minimum  is " << min << endl;
        cout << " Sum is " << sum << endl;
        cout << " Average is " << avg << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- Initialize all variables (good C/C++ practice).
- Use `std::min` and `std::max` rather than roll your own.
- Remove `empty` because by setting the initial values of `min` and `max` correctly it is no longer required.
- Fix the divide by zero error pointed out by R Sahu.

Comment: Thank you, I did't know about the `std::min` and `std::max`or the `limits`. I'm new to this.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Visual Studio defines stdafx.h by default I guess

Comment: @Alf Thanks for the feedback and presumably the downvote. I used the first compiler I had at hand.  I've modified the two lines of code that you had difficulties with. Dish - Yes, VS defines this by default if you create a standard windows console project. You can remove this if you want.